# converting arabic date format to english : System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

Tags: c#, datetime, cultureinfo, culture

In my c# code, I am getting an **Arabic** date from a function, I need to convert this date to **English** format (`UK/US`). I tried with the following code

```
string startdate = "٢٠١٩-٠٩-٠٣";

var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
  startdate, 
 "d MMMM yyyy", 
  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

it *throws exception:*

> System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid
>   DateTime.'

Comment: Note that `ParseExact` tries to create a `DateTime` object which does not have any format (at all). It simply stores any DateTime as a `long` value, `Ticks`. I'm also not sure that `InvariantCulture` is able to understand Arabic dates. An Arabic culture would probably be a better option here.

Comment: I have to go with John on this one.  The description of `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` even mentions that it's "associated with the English language"

Comment: The dupe I linked to shows how to do exactly this... parse a date from Eastern Arabic numerals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this namespace `using System.Globalization;`

```
string arabicTextDate= "٢٠١٩-٠٩-٠٣";
     var str = arabicTextDate
    .Replace('\u0660','0')
    .Replace('\u0661','1')
    .Replace('\u0662','2')
    .Replace('\u0663','3')
    .Replace('\u0664','4')
    .Replace('\u0665','5')
    .Replace('\u0666','6')
    .Replace('\u0667','7')
    .Replace('\u0668','8')
    .Replace('\u0669','9');
    DateTime dt=DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

> Follow this link for fiddle. [Code With Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PYoqkH)

[image]

Comment: it doesn't work for ٢٠١٩-٠٩-٠٣ date

Comment: it's working checkout this link, https://dotnetfiddle.net/pPclmk

Answer (score 1):

You can try convert *digits* (which are *Easten Arabic*) into *Western Arabic* ones (i.e. into `0..9`):

```
  string startdate = @"٢٠١٩-٠٩-٠٣";

  string translated = string.Concat(startdate.Select(c => char.GetNumericValue(c) < 0 
     ? c.ToString()                          // Character, keep intact  
     : char.GetNumericValue(c).ToString())); // Digit! we want them be 0..9 only

  // Arabic language has right to left order, that's why pattern is "yyyy-M-d"
  DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
    translated, // note, not startdate
   "yyyy-M-d", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);

  // English, Great Britain culture
  Console.Write(dateTime.ToString("d MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB")));
```

**Outcome:**

```
  3 September 2019
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f9zbpw)

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the culture of the string you are trying to parse:

```cs
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("YOUR CULTURE CODE"); // Probably "ar-SA"
var startDate = "٢٠١٩-٠٩-٠٣";
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, "d MMMM yyyy", culture);
```

You can find the culture codes here:

http://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that `"d MMMM yyyy"` is the expected format of `startDate`, not the format of `dateTime` (although `DateTime` doesn't have a format, many people make the mistake of thinking it does).

Comment: It doesn't work. it shows culture doesn't exist. I had tried this early